# How to consume webservices over https

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to consume a webservices which are located at https://TestServices/ServiceList.asmx. When I try to add a service reference to my C# library class project my app.config file looks like below:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="TestServicesSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="">
                        </transport>
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://TestServices/ServiceList.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestServicesSoap"
                contract="TestServices.TestServicesSoap" name="TestServicesSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Even when I tried to add a service reference to the **https://TestServices/ServiceList.asmx** for some reason end point address is still pointing to **http://TestServices/ServiceList.asmx**. I tried changing the http to https but I am getting the below error:

**The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via**

What is the right way of consuming the webservices on https?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via)

Answer (score 1):

In the binding you have `<security mode="None"`..., where as I believe if you want to use https, you need to set it to `<security mode="Transport"`...