# The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.Parameter name: via

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have use below below configuration without "https". Now url changed to **"https"**. But I am getting **"The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.Parameter name: via"**  error while calling it.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ERightsPortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>          
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://dev.company.com/jws/ws/EService?WSDL" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ERightsPortBinding" contract="ERights.ERights" name="ERightsPort" />
</client>
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via to fix this recently.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What do you get when you change your `security` tag's mode to `Transport`?

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

We use https services and this is the mode we use -- we use `None` for http in our development environments.

Comment: This works for me but when I called eRights.isMember(userName); it says ... "Cannot find dispatch method for {http://ws.security.company.com/}isMember"

Comment: Sounds like you may be having another issue (which would mean another question).  You could post your contract and implementation (abbreviated versions) to see if anyone can see an issue with your service contract.  But this seems unrelated to your original problem.

Comment: Looks like you already asked another question about this.  If this answered your question, you should mark it as so.  :)

Comment: Thanks David, this worked.. can you please explain WHY this would fix it?  Still confused by what this error message meant in the first place.