# URI scheme 'https' invalid, expected 'http'. Parameter name: via

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012-r2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>  

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="2000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />   
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false" />    
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>    
  </system.webServer>



  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="Complete_Html5.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Complete_Html5.Service1ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Complete_Html5.Service1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>        
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.Service1ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>        
      </serviceBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://www.examplete.com:83/CompleteService/Complete.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" />
      <endpoint address="https://www.examplete.com:83/CompleteService/Complete.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" contract="PMCService.Complete" name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" />
      <endpoint address="https://www.examplete.com:83/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" contract="ReportService.Service1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" />
      <endpoint address="https://www.examplete.com:83/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" contract="ReportService.Service1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <location path="images">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>


  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" cacheControlMaxAge="10:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

I found lots many questions and solution on same forum but I don't get that, each one have same error
but different type causes.
Our website which running fine for `http` and now we have added new ssl certification to `Windows Server 2012 r2` server
and trying to use `https` as well(both `http` and `https`). But when performing operation with `https` gives error as:

> The provided URI scheme `https` is invalid; expected `http`. Parameter name: via.

But wants to run site for both request `http` and `https`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.Parameter name: via](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010637/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via)

Answer (score 9):

You will have to Change your `bindingConfiguration` to support transport security or change your binding to an `basicHttpsBinding` (which is available with WCF 4.5)

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" />        
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

or

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" ... />
```

You can read more in this answer:
[What is the difference between BasicHttpsBinding and WsHttpBinding with Transport security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874529/what-is-the-difference-between-basichttpsbinding-and-wshttpbinding-with-transpor)

Comment: where and what change do I have to make in web.config, and after done that, do I have to update service reference?

Comment: I have tried by making `security mode` to `transport` but it not works. Is there any need to update reference as one of forum suggest me to update that even though change in web.config?

Comment: Well, since any other question about that topic in SO essentially shows, that this is a solution, I'd expect you did not change all or not the correct entries.

Comment: .@TGlatzer, for first option I have made changes only to three places as  bindings>basicHttpBinding>binding>security mode="Transport". Is there need to make changes somewhere else??

Comment: Jup, `Complete_Html5.Service1` uses the default bindingConfiguration for example - you have to adjust that as well...