# Steps to use DotCMIS dll to view all workspaces in alfresco

Tags: .net, alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

can anyone tell me what are the steps, to use DotCMIS dll to view all workspaces in alfresco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CMIS there's no concept of workspace. I guess you mean you want to list the Repositories. To achieve that, as shown in the [official examples](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/getting-started-with-dotcmis.html), you can do the following:

```
//
// AtomPub version
//
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/service/cmis";
parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "admin";
parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "admin";

SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
IList<IRepository> repos = factory.GetRepositories(parameters);

//
// WebServices version
//
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.WebServices;
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesRepositoryService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/RepositoryService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesAclService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/AclService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesDiscoveryService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/DiscoveryService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesMultifilingService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/MultifilingService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesNavigationService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/NavigationService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesObjectService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/ObjectService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesPolicyService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/PolicyService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesRelationshipService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/RelationshipService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.WebServicesVersioningService] = "http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis/VersioningService?wsdl";
parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "admin";
parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "admin";

SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
IList<IRepository> repos = factory.GetRepositories(parameters);
```

Comment: how do i find the AtomPubUrl? How can the same be done if the binding type is 'WebService'

Comment: updated to include more real URLs. Bear in mind the WSDLs are available at `http://your.host.name/alfresco/cmis`

Comment: I am getting the following error                                 Error: The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via

Comment: i used the code for binding type 'WebService' and am getting the error mentioned in the above comment

Comment: Looks like your server uses https then - you should use the https url for your server instead. Hint - you should be able to get the CMIS page up in your browser to check you've got the right URL

Comment: @Gagravarr I am able to get the open the services using http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmis/RepositoryService?wsdl. trying to open the same using http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmis/RepositoryService?wsdl shows that page cannot be displayed.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via