# Pass token from MVC to WCF service

Tags: wcf, token, jwt

I have a MVC app talking to ACS to get token for authentication. It's a claim based application. This works perfectly fine.

I am trying to call WCF service from MVC once authenticated with same taken so that i can use same claims for authorization.

MVC code is as below

```
    var context = (BootstrapContext)identity.BootstrapContext;
        var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.Message);
        binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.SymmetricKey;
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        binding.Security.Message.IssuerBinding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress acsEndPoint = 
    new EndpointAddress("https://ACS namespace/v2/wsfederation");
        binding.Security.Message.IssuerAddress = acsEndPoint;
        binding.Security.Message.IssuedTokenType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt";
        ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = 
new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/TestWCF/Service1.svc"));
        factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
        factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;


        var proxy = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(context.SecurityToken);
        proxy.GetData(1);
```

WCF web config is as below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
  <service name="TestWCF.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpAutoFormat" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"    bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="TestWCF.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TestWCF.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
  <bindings>
  <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-        type:jwt">
                      <issuerMetadata address="https://ACS namespace/v2/wstrust/mex"></issuerMetadata>
        </message>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
</bindings>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true"></serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpAutoFormat">
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="Service1.svc" service="TestWCF.Service1" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Please note my WCF service is not HTTPS also I am using JWT token from ACS. No certificates.

I get below error

The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently initializing your binding with

```
var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.Message)
```

Try changing to

```
var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential)
```

From ([MSDN - WS Transport With Message Credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354508(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> By default, the wsHttpBinding binding provides HTTP communication.
>   When configured for transport security, the binding supports HTTPS
>   communication. HTTPS provides confidentiality and integrity protection
>   for the messages that are transmitted over the wire. However the set
>   of authentication mechanisms that can be used to authenticate the
>   client to the service is limited to what the HTTPS transport supports.
>   Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) offers a
>   TransportWithMessageCredential security mode that is designed to
>   overcome this limitation. When this security mode is configured, the
>   transport security is used to provide confidentiality and integrity
>   for the transmitted messages and to perform the service
>   authentication. However, the client authentication is performed by
>   putting the client credential directly in the message. This allows you
>   to use any credential type that is supported by the message security
>   mode for the client authentication while keeping the performance
>   benefit of transport security mode.

Your web config should have this instead for `<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>`:

```
  <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" issuedTokenType="urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-        type:jwt">
                      <issuerMetadata address="https://ACS namespace/v2/wstrust/mex"></issuerMetadata>
        </message>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
```

See also the following answer for some additional info as well: [StackOverflow - The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via)

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Please note i am not using any certificates.. NO HTTPS anywhere

Comment: mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"... If i put mode as None it works fine but if i put it as Message or TransportWithMessageCredential then i get different errors. Do i need any kind of certificates or anything?

Comment: Finally it works. we do need <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">.. Apart from that we need WCF to be secured (HTTPS) and my certificate was issued for my computername and i was using local host. Also i was using JWT token so I had to serialize it before sending though channelfactory. I have whole thing working but not sure how to upload the working solution here. It took almost 3 days to make it work... but it works  smoothly now :)