# Using Both HTTP and HTTPS in same WCF Binding - Changing <security mode="Transport"> to <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"> In Code

Tags: c#, wcf, https, wsdl

I have an autogenerated binding from a WSDL file in a Visual Studio project that looks like this:

```xml
<binding name="XServiceSoap" 
         maxBufferPoolSize="16777216"
         maxBufferSize="16777216" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="16777216">
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" 
                   proxyCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

and the client looks like this:

```xml
<endpoint address="http://uri/XService.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="XServiceSoap"
          contract="XService.XServiceSoap" 
          name="XServiceSoap"/>
```

In the code, I'm easily able to change the endpoint address (and credentials) using

```cs
using WPFApp.XService;
var xServiceSoapClient = new XServiceSoapClient("XServiceSoap");
xServiceSoapClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(NEW_ENDPOINT);
xServiceSoapClient
    .ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = NEW_USERNAME;
xServiceSoapClient
    .ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = NEW_PASSWORD;
```

But if I try using a non-http endpoint, I got thrown an exception `The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.`

This error makes sense to me (ex. [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via)), but I want the same binding to support both HTTP and HTTPS when I change the endpoint (test vs prod server). How do I do this in code with the built in soap client? I don't see an option in the `xServiceSoapClient` to change the `security mode`, ex. I don't see a `XServiceSoapclient.Security.Mode` option where it can be changed.

I can confirm when I change the `app.config` manually from TransportCredentialOnly to Transport, https connections work without throwing an exception.

Thank you!

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for the WCF client has an overload that takes two parameters, `binding` and `endpoint`

you can use this overload to pass your desired security mode:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

var xServiceSoapClient = new xServiceSoapClient(binding, "XServiceSoap");
```

This is the general idea, using the designated object rather then the service client object that is not meant for the above kind of manipulations.

Comment: Wanted to mention this was exactly what I needed, though I used `basicHttpBinding` instead of `WSHttpBinding` since there were some compatibility issues.